# using boost::assign with a std::set nested inside a std::map

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use `boost::assign` to emulate C++11 initialization of a `std::map` containing a `std::set`.

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

typedef std::map< uint32_t, std::set< uint32_t> > the_map_t;

the_map_t data = boost::assign::map_list_of( 1, boost::assign::list_of(10)(20)(30) )
                                           ( 2, boost::assign::list_of(12)(22)(32) )
                                           ( 3, boost::assign::list_of(13)(23)(33) )
                                           ( 4, boost::assign::list_of(14)(24)(34) );
```

Initialisation of `std::set` using `boost::assign::list_of` works as expected when used on its own, but when I try the above code the assignment is ambiguous at the point where the `std::set`'s    constructor is called:

```
map-assign.cpp:16:   instantiated from here
include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:101: error: call of overloaded set(const   boost::assign_detail::generic_list<int>&) is ambiguous
include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_set.h:188: note: candidates are: 
    std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set(
        const std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>&) 
        [with _Key = unsigned int, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned int>]

include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_set.h:145: note:                 
    std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::set(
        const _Compare&, const _Alloc&) 
        [with _Key = unsigned int, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned int>]
```

How can I resolve this ambiguity error?

Comment: Does `list_of(10U)(20U)(30U)` help at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case `boost::assign::map_list_of` needs a hint for second template argument - `<uint32_t, std::set< uint32_t> >`. Therefore line

```
the_map_t data = boost::assign::map_list_of(...);
```

becomes

```
the_map_t data = boost::assign::map_list_of<uint32_t, std::set< uint32_t> >(...);
```

Comment: cheers that works but I believe  have uncovered a bug within `boost::assign`, see: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Typedef-rejected-when-disambiguating-a-call-to-boost-assign-td4637775.html.