# Populating the std::map of boost::function with boost::assign::map_list_of

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-function

I would like to create a key-value data structure that would be useful for responding to the events of string matching to regex patterns. So I am trying to work it out with a Boost library:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<boost::regex, boost::function<void(void)> > regex_callback;

void SuOpenedCallback()
{
}

void SuClosedCallback()
{
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Don't pay attention to these definitions... 
    boost::regex su_opened  ("^(\\w+)\\s(\\d+)\\s([\\d:]+)\\s(\\w+)\\s"
                            "su: pam_unix\\(su:session\\): session opened for user{1}\\s([\\w\\d]+)\\sby{1}\\s([\\w\\d]+)\\(uid=([\\d]+)\\)$"); 
    boost::regex su_closed  ("^(\\w+)\\s(\\d+)\\s([\\d:]+)\\s(\\w+)\\s"
                            "su: pam_unix\\(su:session\\): session closed for user{1}\\s([\\w\\d]+)$");

    //Compilation error:
    regex_callback resolver = boost::assign::map_list_of<boost::regex, boost::function<void(void)> >
        (su_opened, boost::bind(&SuOpenedCallback))
        (su_closed, boost::bind(&SuClosedCallback));

//...

}
```

When I try to compile it (unfortunately I am forced to use quite old software - gcc 4.4.7, boost 1.41, therefore C++11 support is very limited):

```
 g++ boost_regexp.cpp -o test -lboost_regex -std=c++0x
```

compilation fails with this error:

> `boost_regexp.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
>   boost_regexp.cpp:58: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ in
>   ‘resolver = boost::assign::map_list_of(const Key&, const T&) [with Key
>   = boost::regex, T = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>](((const boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(),
>   boost::_bi::list0>&)((const boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(),
>   boost::_bi::list0>*)(& boost::bind [with R =
>   void](SuOpenedCallback))))).boost::assign_detail::generic_list<T>::operator()
>   [with U = boost::regex, U0 = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(),
>   boost::_bi::list0>, T = std::pair<boost::basic_regex<char,
>   boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>,
>   boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>](((const
>   boost::regex&)((const boost::regex*)(& su_closed))), ((const
>   boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>&)((const
>   boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(), boost::_bi::list0>*)(&
>   boost::bind [with R = void](SuClosedCallback)))))’
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_map.h:251:
>   note: candidates are: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&
>   std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::map<_Key,
>   _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>, _Tp =
>   boost::function<void()>, _Compare = std::less<boost::basic_regex<char,
>   boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>, _Alloc
>   = std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>,
>   boost::function<void()>]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_map.h:266:
>   note:                 std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&
>   std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator=(std::map<_Key, _Tp,
>   _Compare, _Alloc>&&) [with _Key = boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>, _Tp =
>   boost::function<void()>, _Compare = std::less<boost::basic_regex<char,
>   boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>, _Alloc
>   = std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>,
>   boost::function<void()>]
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/bits/stl_map.h:286:
>   note:                 std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&
>   std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::operator=(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>) [with _Key = boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char,
>   boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>, _Tp = boost::function<void()>,
>   _Compare = std::less<boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>, _Alloc
>   = std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>,
>   boost::function<void()>] make: *** [all] Error 1`

Seems like my problem is close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125924/using-boostassign-with-a-stdset-nested-inside-a-stdmap), however, it does not inspire me. It would be nice if someone could show me the mistake.

**ANSWER** As @sehe has mentioned, this code is correct for up-to-date versions of gcc but cannot be handled with gcc 4.4. Unfortunately for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that should just compile.

You might try the more direct approach (without bind) though, which is probably (a lot) easier on the compiler:

```
regex_callback resolver = boost::assign::map_list_of<boost::regex, boost::function<void(void)> >
    (su_opened, &SuOpenedCallback)
    (su_closed, &SuClosedCallback);
```

**EDIT** Since that didn't work, try making it more explicit still:

```
typedef boost::function<void(void)> Func;

regex_callback resolver = boost::assign::map_list_of<boost::regex, Func >
    (su_opened, Func(boost::bind(&SuOpenedCallback)))
    (su_closed, Func(boost::bind(&SuClosedCallback)));

// or:
regex_callback resolver = boost::assign::map_list_of<boost::regex, Func >
    (su_opened, Func(&SuOpenedCallback))
    (su_closed, Func(&SuClosedCallback));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this crashes the compilation with almost the same error.

Comment: That's not crashing though. I can only say, live with it or upgrade the compiler :(

Comment: @VitalyIsaev Added one more desperate-attempt workaround idea :)

Comment: thank you for the provided examples. Unfortunately my outdated gcc could not compile any of them, but gcc 4.8.2 did it properly. Unfortunately I can't update my workstation so I'll try to find other solution.